# Centered page with exception

Tags: html, css, center, margins

im trying to keep the main div always center but when resizing the browser window to the minimum sizes starting from 900px, how can I make the "main" stay all left and only in bigger screens or above 900px he starts to center the page in the middle?

Thanks in advance

CSS:

```
body {
   font: 24px Helvetica;
   background: #999999;
   min-width: 900px;
   margin: 0;
  }

#main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
}


header {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

article {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <header>header</header>
 <div id='main'>

     <nav>nav</nav>
     <article>article</article>

 </div>
 <footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Consider looking into media queries for something like this.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following media query:

```
#main {
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    #main {
        margin:auto;
        width: 900px; // will need some sort of width adding either here or above for a default width
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5bvw8LL3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I totally forgot about Media Queries but somehow this solution it's not working. All page keeps on the left.

Comment: I think it was some kind of bug with CODA because now after restarting the app it's working fine, but the NAV and Article Divs have their width fixed. Im using SAFARI 8 for MAC. Thanks.

Comment: Ah sounds like it may cache the style sheet

Comment: Yeah probably. This is a simple code and yet drives me crazy because your code is working perfectly but now the "nav" and "article" don't resize automatically while resizing the browser window. Both divs together stay at 900px, so when I try to use percentages, the page ignores your code and align everything to the left again.

Comment: When we remove the rest of the code it works great, like your example, but using my complete code it doesn't work because both DIV's don't get bigger than 900px and both divs lose their "flexible" size.

Comment: Could it be because of the min-width on the body?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Finally I found the solution, I removed the Media Queries and in the Main Div, I used the min and max width. Now it's working perfectly. Thanks again for trying to help me. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, the language in your question starts to get a little confusing with the typos.  So what is clear to me is that you want some CSS to apply below a certain screen width and other CSS to apply above a certain screen width.  This can be achieved using media queries.  Please see below:

The following CSS applies to screen with widths up to 900px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #main {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right auto;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

The following CSS applies to screen with widths over 900px.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

You can read more about media queries here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry about that. Yes, that's what I wanted, but somehow this code it's not working either...and I can't figure why...